# Spring Cloud Stream - Batch receiving of messages

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-kafka

I want to fetch a batch of messages (say 10000 messages) from a Kafka topic at regular intervals (for bulk processing all the 10k records at once instead of one-by-one).

Is there a way to achieve this in a Spring Cloud Stream processor? If so, are there any snippets or any examples that I can refer to?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, unfortunately there is still no `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.ListenerMode.batch` support on the `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.TARGET.consumer.` level. Feel free to raise an issue on the matter.

Meanwhile as a workaround I can suggest to use Spring Integration `Aggregator` as a Kafka topic consumer to really batch records on the application level. and only after that send them for processing.

Well, another workaround might be like using Spring Integration Kafka (`KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`) manually, not Kafka Binder. Or just use Spring Kafka with its `@KafkaListener` and `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean with appropriate `batchListener` option.

Comment: There is already an [open issue to add batching to the binder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/70)